# Wordpress + php + mysql High cpu usage

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx, cpu

I'm load testing a production server using **wordpress**, **php 7.2** and **mysql**  `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB`, with 4 Core i7 CPUs and 10GB Ram running on **ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. The problem is even with a low load, like 5 users per second, all 4 CPUs spike to 100% and they persist. After a while CPUs are full and I only get Error 500. Also, all of my modules are up to date.

I tried disabling all the plugins in wordpress and ran the same test, but the problem persisted.

I also used some plugins to optimize database like `wp-optimize`, but no luck. The `/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log` file is also empty.

[Result of load testing after only few sec including htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRoW1.jpg)

[Datadog's monitoring dashboard of the related test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akhdH.png)

As shown in pictures above you can comprehend that `mysqld` is using too much CPU for no reason.

I also ran **mysqltuner** and this is the result:

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.19 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Logged in using credentials passed on the command line
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log exists
[--] Log file: /var/log/mysql/error.log(7K)
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/log/mysql/error.log is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/log/mysql/error.log contains 8 warning(s).
[!!] /var/log/mysql/error.log contains 3 error(s).
[--] 3 start(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 1) 2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2020-05-09 12:28:42 140719406492800 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2020-05-09 10:52:43 139784491093120 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2 shutdown(s) detected in /var/log/mysql/error.log
[--] 1) 2020-05-09 12:32:02 140713171822336 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2020-05-09 10:53:00 139784442357504 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 112.0K (Tables: 4)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 38.7M (Tables: 52)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 48m 13s (73K q [25.317 qps], 1K conn, TX: 978M, RX: 11M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 96% / 4%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 9.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 10.6G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 4.7G global + 6.9M per thread (800 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 511M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 6.5G (67.07% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 10.6G (108.28% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/73K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 25% (204/800)
[!!] Aborted connections: 10.65%  (193/1812)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 12K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 83% (2K on disk / 3K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 84% (284 created / 1K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 97% (222 open / 228 opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(400) is upper than number of tables(303)
[OK] Open file limit used: 6% (304/4K)
[!!] Table locks acquired immediately: 84%

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 511.6M
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 4 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.4% (24M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/10.0M
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (695K cached / 152 reads)
[OK] Write Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (18 cached / 18 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 3.9G/112.0K
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 500.0M * 2/3.9G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 3
[--] InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk Size not used or defined in your version
[!!] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 85.36% (1493 hits/ 1749 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 0% (1 hits/ 0 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 89.4% (26K cached / 2K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: STATEMENT
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysql/error.log file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connections and network issues
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Optimize queries and/or use InnoDB to reduce lock wait
```

**mysql** config in  `/etc/mysqld/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
general_log = on
skip-name-resolve
innodb_read_io_threads=4
innodb_write_io_threads=4
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
#
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size= 4000M
max_connections =800
wait_timeout=100
interactive_timeout=100
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_limit=2M
tmp_table_size=500M
max_heap_table_size=500M
thread_cache_size=4
performance_schema=ON
innodb_log_file_size=500M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=3
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2
```

`/var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 3.9G
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-09 12:36:16 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.46-86.2 started; log sequence number 1832982
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139632989665024 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Warning] 'user' entry 'wp_user@server' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Warning] 'db' entry 'db_name wp_user@server' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2020-05-09 12:36:17 139638727916672 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 18.04
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck
I appreciate your help, here are the results respectively:
[Global Status](https://pastebin.com/kf47D4t0),
[Global Variables](https://pastebin.com/uxeaRVze) ,
[Full Process List](https://pastebin.com/WmkQJgy7),
[InnoDb Stat](https://pastebin.com/apvT3JSN).
Also about the SSD, no, there's no such device on MySQL Host server.

Comment: Any SSD or NVME devices used for data storage?

Comment: @WilsonHauck Nope!

Comment: @WilsonHauck ```SCSI storage controller``` this is the only storage on my server!

Comment: @WilsonHauck this is also the result of iostat you said:
[iostat before running the test](https://pastebin.com/uh2Ujbct),
[iostat after running the test](https://pastebin.com/2BS1JCNZ)

Comment: @WilsonHauck Oh LOL, my bad. Here is the variables:
[Global Vars](https://pastebin.com/RFSWxLCM)
Actually I read your comment yesterday and waited 24hours to get the results but when I wanted to go into DB, it looked as if it's down. I think the load testing has done this to it, so I had to restart it and run a test and then take the results.
In my previous comment I provided iostat.

Comment: Thank you for the posted data. The Global Status is only actually the last 1/2 of SHOW GLOBAL Variables.
The Global Variables is only the last part of SGV.
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; appears to have activity for much less than 24 hours of UPTIME (since MySQL started).
Optional very helpful information, if available includes - ulimit -a for a Linux/Unix list of limits, for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck This is the last piece of info you wanted, let me know if I missed or screwed up something!
[ulimit -a result](https://pastebin.com/vgHp4uGq)

Comment: Please pick up SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; in 24 hours for more meaningful analysis.
The posting of about 17 minutes ago, called Global Vars is actually SHOW GLOBAL STATUS for 2500 seconds. Tomorrow or today, SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; posted to pastebin.com would be great.  Thank you and have a GREAT week.

Comment: @WilsonHauck will do definitely! Thanks mate, you too!

Comment: @WilsonHauck
Hey, more than 24 Hours has passed and I did what you told me, let me know if there was anything else needed! I appreciate it.
[global stat](https://pastebin.com/iyecU3cL),
[global vars](https://pastebin.com/DFxgUSrE)

Comment: Thank you, will try to complete analysis within 24 hours.  Do you have flexibility to use Skype Talk?  I am in UTC -6 hrs.  Skype ID wlhauck@aol.com

Comment: @WilsonHauck I sent you a message on Skype! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section:

```
thread_cache_size=256  # from 4 for default minimum
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to enable higher IOPS
read_rnd_buffer_size=128K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 256
read_buffer_size=256K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 828
```

These changes will reduce CPU busy on your server.  There are more opportunities available to improve your my.cnf.

Observations:
OS swap space is at 0.  6GB for your 10GB server would be reasonable and avoid Out of memory.
Select_scan RPhr of 1546 could be reduced with appropriate indexes on tables.
At www.mysqlservertuning.com on our FAQ page we have tips on 
Q. How can I find JOINS or QUERIES not using indexes?
to improve response time and reduce CPU busy percentage by using indexes.